# How to point out an intent in Settings like Android does

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

This is my first question here in SO. Hope someone will help me.
I started an intent to let the user enable the NFC like this:

`public void onClick(View v) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS), 0);
}`

The intent works and the button let me go to the settings to activate the NFC.
I want also that the row where NFC is would be pointed out, just like Android does when you search for something in the Settings app - maybe an image would be much more helpful: 
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fej9k.png)

As you can see the NFC row is pointed out to help the user to find it. How can I do it too?
I looked everywhere but I can't find nothing.

Thanks in advance,
Aspa

Comment: Do you want the position on screen of where another app has information? If so, you cannot, unless on a rooted device, as this goes against the Android security model.

Comment: I don't think it works like this. I'll make you an example.
On Android 6.+ go to Settings, search for "nfc", tap on the first result -> the app shows the correct row where NFC settings are. I want to do the same type of animation/selection but starting from my app. All the Intent code works well, I just want to add this particular visual effect which I like a lot :)